# setw within a function to return an ostream

Tags: c++, cout, ostream, setw

here is my function

```
ostream margain(std::string firstWord)
{
    ostream x;
    x << std::setw(20) << firstWord;
    return x;
}
```

in main I want to use the function as follow

`````````````````````````````````````
std::cout<< margain("start") << "````````````````````````````````````" << std::endl;
// print things out
//then
std::cout<< margain("End") << "````````````````````````````````````" << std::endl;
`````````````````````````````````````

I get the output, start or end is not shown, and the return value is

> 0````````````````````````````````````

how can I fix it? and why?

**Edit:**
I know that the function is what causing that, because if I add this

> cout << std::setw(20) << firstWord;
>   in the function, It prints right,

I fixed it, not the best way, but as

calling the function as

> margain(std::cout, "End") <<
>   "~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~=~" << endl;

the function looks like

```
ostream& margain(ostream& stream, std::string firstWord)
{
    stream << std::left << std::setw(10) << firstWord;
    return stream;
}
```

anyone know better way?

Comment: when you declare x in margain, is there a compiler error happen when you do that? as I do it this moment I was told that error on 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits>' because no appropriate default constructor available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are printing the value of the ostream, not value of `firstword`. The `ostream x` in this case is an unopened stream, so it doesn't "do" anything. Because the compiler allows to conversion to either `bool` (C++11) or `void *` (before C++11), the "value" from that conversion is printed. Note that any operations on `x` will not affect `cout`.

The easiest solution, I would think is to actually add `std::setw(20)` to your output line:

`````````````````````````````````````
std::cout<< std::setw(20 << "End" << "````````````````````````````````````" << std::endl;
`````````````````````````````````````

The other choice would be to pass the `std::cout` to `margain`, and return the `std::string`, something like this:

```
std::string margain(ostream& x, const std::string& firstWord)
{
    x << std::setw(20);
    return firstWord;
}
```

then you could do:

`````````````````````````````````````
std::cout<< margain(cout, "start") << "````````````````````````````````````" << std::endl;
`````````````````````````````````````

But it's not exactly flexible or "neat".

The third option is of course to have a `MarginString` class:

`````````````````````````````````````
class MarignString
{
  private:
     int margin;
     std::string str;
  public:
     MarginString(int margin, std::string str) margin(margin), str(str) {}
     operator std::string() { return str; }
     friend std::ostream& operator(std::ostream& os, const MarginString& ms);
 };


 std::ostream& operator(std::ostream& os, const MarginString& ms)
 {
     os << std::setw(ms.margin) << ms.str;
     return os;
 }

 ...
 std::cout<< MarginString(20, "start") << "````````````````````````````````````" << std::endl;
`````````````````````````````````````

Note that this last way is probably not that great either... ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
struct margin
{
    margin(std::string word) : word(word) { }

    friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, margin const& m)
    {
         return os << std::setw(20) << m.word;
    }

private:
    std::string word;
};
```

Comment: I think the `operator<<` function needs to go outside the `struct` (or be a non-friend but static function)

Comment: It may well compile, but the first argument to `operator <<` should be the `ostream`, and in your case, it will be a `this`, right? Or does sticking `friend` on the front of a function have a similar effect to static, that it's no longer a member function?